# Mobile view adjustment on flexdashboard in R

Tags: r, shiny, responsive-design, r-markdown, flexdashboard

On the flexdashboard, mobile view and desktop view are different for the navbar which is absolutely fine. The view of share button on the desktop without menu tag looks great as below (desktop view). However, share tag is coming next to menu icon as below (mobile view) on the mobile view. How can I remove this tag (the text of **share**) on mobile view or how can I modify this text tag?

```
---
title: "test"
author: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: ["menu"]
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

**Desktop View**

[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]